# PyCharm and Pypy - Unresolved reference

Tags: python, pycharm, pypy

For some weird reason, my PyCharm loves to show unresolved errors everywhere.
But only with pypy. The source runs just fine, even PyCharm can run the code perfect.

But the red lines everywhere are really annoying.
**The problem**: [image: http://i.imgur.com/o5BqCZP.jpg]

Ps.: I tried the Invalidate cache method, but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you configure the interpreter correctly? Also did you add the library paths to interpreter?

Comment: Are you using virtual envs?

Comment: Nope. I don't use them even with the default (ActiveState) Python.

Comment: It's configured properly, but I feared there will be problems if I add it to PATH. I'll try to remove the ActiveState Python and add pypy as default.

Comment: No, it didn't help. Sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>It's a known bug with PyPy support in PyCharm,</strike> see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9546.

**The bug seems to be fixed now.**

Comment: Thank you very much. Hope the team will fix the issue as it is really annoying. (Especially since pypy is so often used.)